# Insert ST_Geom Using Query Oracle (GIS)

Tags: oracle, oracle-spatial

I have a question.

I want to run an insert of geometry using the ST(Geometry) data type using a query (Oracle database).

I tried using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO <TABLE> (OBJECTID, "NO", NAMA_OBJEK, JENIS_OBJE, ALAMAT, SHAPE)
VALUES (
0,
0,
'example',
'example',
'example',
SDE.ST_GEOMETRY('POINT(106.89162, -6.15505)', 4328));
```

I encountered an error in the query with the error message:
SQL Error [28595] [99999]: ORA-28595: Extproc agent: Invalid DLL Path
ORA-06512: at "SDE.ST_GEOMETRY_SHAPELIB_PKG", line 12.

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMmyM.png)

Why am I unable to run the insert, while when I run the query with the ST_Geometry function:

```
SELECT SDE.ST_length(shape) AS area
FROM Table
WHERE SDE.ST_length(shape) > 1000;
```

there is no error occurring. Is there a mistake in my query causing the error, or is there something else?

Comment: (This has nothing at all to do with Oracle Spatial: you are using ESRI's own implementation of spatial data types in Oracle. I suggest you remove the `oracle-spatial` tag and add the `ESRI` tag instead).

Comment: ESRI's implementation of the code to process their spatial types uses Oracle's "external process" aka "extproc" mechanism. This mechanism allows PL/SQL code (here the ST_GEOMETRY constructor) to invoke external code without endangering the stability or security of the database kernel: the database uses an inter-process communication mechanism to call C/C++ functions in a shared library (DLL in windows parlance). The ` ORA-28595: Extproc agent: Invalid DLL Path` message indicates that the PL/SQL package (`SDE.ST_GEOMETRY_SHAPELIB_PKG`) is unable to invoke functions in that library.

Comment: Using external callouts requires an appropriate setup (some config files need manually updating in the Oracle installation, the shared libraries must have the right permissions, ...). That setup can be tricky, but the instructions for doing so for the ESRI shared library(ies) should have been provided by ESRI in the installation manual. The process has been gradually simplified over the Oracle versions, so it is important to use the proper instructions for the version of Oracle you use (and the version of ESRI you use).

Comment: Without knowing the versions you are running, it is difficult to diagnose. With the latest releases of Oracle (12.2 or 19c or later), the configuration file is in `$ORACLE_HOME/hs/admin/extproc.ora`; you can check logs in `$ORACLE_HOME/hs/log`. The trace files in there may help diagnose what happens.

Comment: To get a proper resolution, I recommend check with whoever in your organization did the installation of ESRI support in your oracle database. If he/she cannot help, then I recommend you submit a support ticket with ESRI. You could also submit a ticket with Oracle support, but there is a good chance you get told to call ESRI support instead.

Comment: You can read about Oracle's extrproc mechanism here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/external-procedures.html#GUID-230B2B41-2A6F-4756-AEC0-DBC99DCA8A37

Answer (score 0):

Instead of SDE.ST_GEOMETRY you can simply insert a geometry using:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> (OBJECTID, SHAPE)
VALUES (
0,
SDO_GEOMETRY('POINT(106.89162 -6.15505)', 4328));
```

The native spatial data type SDO_GEOMETRY perfectly works with your ESRI toolset.

Your query:

```
SELECT SDE.ST_length(shape) AS area
FROM Table
WHERE SDE.ST_length(shape) > 1000;
```

does not make sense for point data.
Nevertheless, the syntax for area and length calculation using SDO_GEOMETRY you can find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/SDO_GEOM-reference.html#GUID-0D52F048-18B4-4A2C-B5BF-6A5F6BD3E113).

Answer (score 0):

One more note:
https://epsg.io/4328 is flagged as "Deprecated".